# AngularJS - Error '_' not defined

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

When I try to use lodash in my angular applications (built from angular-seeds) it's returning `'_' not defined` but the lodash package is in my `node_modules`. What else do i need to do to include it?

Comment: Are you using any build tools? If so you may need to add the module to the build script. Otherwise just include the js file just like any other script tag `<script src="/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Your angular application executes in the browser. What the node_modules folder contains is irrelevant. angular-seeds seems to use bower for application dependencies. node modules are used by the tooling (karma, etc.)

Comment: @JBNizet It's being more and more common for people to ditch bower and use npm exclusively. Personally I prefer the set up you're describing (mainly because of how bower resolves conflicts), but it doesn't apply to everyone.

Comment: @jfadich But the fact is... that it applies to the OP.

Comment: @JBNizet telling OP mode modules are used by tooling doesn't help op load the node module that they are specifically trying to use.

Comment: I didn't just say that. I also said that **bower** is what should be used in his setup to get application dependencies. Just like it's used to get angular. He shouldn't use node_modules at all: the node_modules directory isn't served by the web server, which serves everything in `/app`. bower_components is under `/app`, because that's where the application dependencies are supposed to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The packages that you have installed using 'npm' are saved in node_modules that are used for server side whereas packages installed using 'bower' are saved in 'public/lib' folder. So the correct way to install lodash for angularjs is

```
bower install --save lodash
```

Answer (score 0):

Having lodash in your node_module doesn't do everything by itself. This problem usually occurs when you have not included the actual file. Add it to your index.

`<script src="/node_modules/pathToYourLodash/lodash.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I was missing an `import _ from "lodash"` statement from my page.